# Passing values between variables of host and kernel Code in a loop in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am in trouble passing values between host code and kernel code due to some vector data types. The following code/explanation is just for referencing my problem, my code is much bigger and complicated. With this small example, hopefully, I will be able to explain where I am having a problem. I f anything more needed please let me know.

```
std::vector<vector<double>> output;

for (int i = 0;i<2; i++)
{
  auto& out = output[i];
  sum =0;
  for (int l =0;l<3;l++)
  {
   for (int j=0;j<4; j++)
   {
    if (some condition is true)
     { out[j+l] = 0.;}
    sum+= .....some addition...
   }
 out[j+l] = sum
 }
}
```

Now I want to parallelize this code, from the second loop. This is what I have done in host code:

```
cl::buffer out = (context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, output.size(), &output, NULL)
```

Then, I have set the arguments

```
cl::SetKernelArg(0, out);
```

Then the loop,

```
for (int i = 0,i<2, i++)
{
  auto& out = output[i];
  // sending some more arguments(which are changing accrding to loop) for sum operations
  queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(.......)
  queue.enqueuereadbuffer(.....,&out,...)
 }
```

In Kernel Code:

```
__kernel void sumout(__global double* out, ....)
{
  int l = get_global_id(0);
  int j = get_global_id(1);
    if (some condition is true)
     { out[j+l] = 0.;  // Here it goes out of the loop then
       return}
    sum+= .....some addition... 
     }
 out[j+l] = sum
}
```

So now, in if condition **out[j+l]** is getting 0 in the **loop**. So out value is regularly changing. In normal code, it is a reference pointer to a vector. I am not able to read the values in **output** from **out** during my kernel and host code. I want to read the values in **output[i]** for every **out[j+l]**. But I am confused due this buffer and vector.

just for more clarification,**output** is a vector of vector and **out** is reference vector to output vector. I need to update values in **output** for every change in **out**. Since these are vectors, I passed **out** as cl buffer. I hope it is clear.
Please let me know, if the code is required, I will try to provide as much as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending pointers of vectors to opencl(ofcourse they are contiguous on pointer level) but whole data is not contiguous in memory since each inner vector points to different memory area. Opencl cannot map host pointers to device memory and there is no such command in this api.

You could use vector of arrays(latest version) or pure arrays.

Comment: turgul buyukisik - I did not understand it pretty well!! You are saying instead of vectors of vectors, use vectors of arrays. i am passing out as memory buffer and for every update in out, I want to update output[i]. Can you explain it a little more?
Is it possible to use output as buffer and storing the values inside kernel code directly?

Comment: first vector element data is between 100 and 200 for example. Then second vector element data is between 5000 and 5100. But their pointers are contiguous in memory, sometihng like 50 and 51 but your data is in 100-200 and 5000-5100 and buffer needs sometihng like 100-200 and 200-300. You should use contiguous structures like arrays or vector of arrays(latest c++ version only maybe). If you are dynamically building your data, then you can just change an array with a bigger one only when needed and use same for smaller data.

Comment: Thanks, I understood, what you are trying to say. But I am having this problem with many variables. If you can, Please refer to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593498/declaring-and-defining-pointer-vetors-of-vectors-in-opencl-kernel) question.