# declaring and defining pointer vetors of vectors in OpenCL Kernel

Tags: opencl

I have a variable which is vector of vector, And in c++, I am easily able to define and declare it but in OpenCL Kernel, I am facing the issues. Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
std::vector<vector <double>> filter;
for (int m= 0;m<3;m++)
{
   const auto& w = filters[m];
   -------sum operation using w
}
```

Now Here, I can easily referencing the values of **filters[m]** in **w**, but I am not able to do this OpenCl kernel file. Here is what I have tried,but it is giving me wrong output.

In host code:-

```
filter_dev = cl::Buffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,filter_size,(void*)&filters,&err);

filter_dev_buff = cl::Buffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,filter_size,NULL,&err);

kernel.setArg(0, filter_dev);
kernel.setArg(1, filter_dev_buff);
```

In kernel code:

```
 __kernel void forward_shrink(__global double* filters,__global double* weight)
{
 int i = get_global_id[0];   // I have tried to use indiviadual values of i in filters j, just to check the output, but is not giving the same values as in serial c++ implementation
 weight = &filters[i];
 ------ sum operations using weight
 }
```

Can anyone help me? Where I am wrong or what can be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing multiple things wrong with your vectors.

First of all `(void*)&filters` doesn't do what you want it to do. `&filters` doesn't return a pointer to the beginning of the actual data. For that you'll have to use `filters.data()`.

Second you can't use an array of arrays in OpenCL (or vector of vectors even less). You'll have to flatten the array yourself to a 1D array before you pass it to a OpenCL kernel.

Comment: Okay, I was just looking for the way to use array of arrays or vector vectors in OpenCL kernel.  I did not know, that,it is not possible. Is there any other way I can use it? As I have multiple loops, and then I can't parallelize almost half of my loops. Is there any way that I pass vector of vector(or any other 2D type) in Kernel file and get a 1D from it inside kernel file.?

Comment: It's not possible to automatically do it but all 2D arrays are possible to be implemented as 1D arrays since in the computer memory the will be in 1D anyways. You will just have to index them differently. And personally I find 1D arrays much easier to operate with.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try to that. In my actual implementation, I have used 3D vector i.e. vector of vector of vectors. `std::vector<vector<vector<double>>> weights`. And then in loop, i have obtained individual vector and pursued the operation. Can you tell me the way to convert this vector into 1D vector?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/17108/ this should answer most of your questions

Comment: Thanks, for the information about vector of vector. I have changed my 2d and #d vector to 1D vector to use it in OpenCl kernel. But I am still facing some issues in passing values from host to kernel. Can you see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719063/passing-values-of-vector-in-the-opencl-kernel) question?