# passing values of vector in the OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl

I have created a vector with some values. Then Created a cl_buffer for that vector and pass it to the OpenCL kernel using kernel Arguments. Like this:

In host Code:

```
std::vector<cl_double> inp;
inp.resize(1024);
for( int i = 0; i<1024;i++)
{
  inp[i] = i;
}
        filter_kernel = cl::Buffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,sizeof(cl_double)*inp.size(),(void*)&inp[0],&err); // also tried (void*)inp.data()

kernel.setArg(0, filter_kernel);
```

In Kernel Code:

```
__kernel void test(__global double* inp)
 {
   for(int m = 0;m<10;m++)
   {
    printf("inp values are : %d \n",inp[m]);
   }
 }
```

This is just and example of showing, how I am passing values in the vector to OpenCL kernel in my program. Is there something wrong with it? As when I print the values, I am getting some random garbage values every time.

I am using MacOS system and Xcode. Device is Intel HD graphics 4000

Comment: You should be using `kernel.setArg(0, filter_kernel)` rather than using `inp` the pointer to the memory in the host code.

Comment: Ohh yes, I wrote it wrong here by mistake, but in my code I wrote it like you have mentioned. I corrected it now.

Comment: If you provide a complete minimal example that demonstrates the failure, others may be able to reproduce it and diagnose the problem more easily.

Comment: I don't think so, Actually its link with one whole library so it will not be possible. Otherwise would have provided it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just compiling the answer, as all the points(in comments) made it work together.

1) change the data type to float from double as Intel does not work with double properly and gives incorrect result.

2) Other mistake was of size, while passing the size in buffer and during readbuffer, it should be inp*sizeof(float) as we are using float and not double now!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR you'll need to map the memory region so that the device can see it. Check https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html . Also I would recommned reading  [the Intel tutorial on the subject.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-the-most-from-opencl-12-how-to-increase-performance-by-minimizing-buffer-copies-on-intel-processor-graphics)

Also HD 4000 shouldn't have double support. Are you sure that the code is running on the GPU and not CPU?

Comment: Yes, it is able to support _double_ . Okay. So I have used CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR now and writing the data using **enqueueWritebuffer**. It is copying the data, but not whole. Like I have inp of size 4096 and when reading, I am getting correct values from 0- 511 only.  I am providing the size of buffer as inp.size().

Comment: well size is size in bytes and double is 8 bytes so only values from 0-511 would tell that you are not doing sizeof(double) * inp.size()

Comment: My mac is giving device 0 as the Intel CPU and device 1 as the HD 4000.  `cl_khr_fp64` is listed in the OpenCL extensions for CPU but not the HD 4000.  If I run a simple (a+b) with `#pramga OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable`, the compiler doesn't complain but it gives a completely incorrect result for the HD 4000.  The same kernel works fine on device 0.